# Authorities on Dutch Minhogim

Tags: minhag

Does anyone know of any rabbonim who are considered experts/authoritative in regards to Dutch minhogim. I know Rabbi Hamburger is considered the go-to authority for minhog Ashkenaz at large, but are there any such rabbonim for the Dutch minhogim? Looking for resources/contact to learn more about Dutch Jewry (Minhog Amsterdam specifically)

Comment: Are you familiar with the sefer Minhagei Amsterdam? It might be worthwhile to contact the editor or others from B"M Binyan Ariel in Amsterdam. https://seforimcenter.com/Minhagei-Amsterdam__p-5024.aspx

Comment: I have the sefer. It appears to be based on an older sefer. I'm looking for other mekorim.

Comment: I meant contacting Rabbi Yehuda Hilleman directly. Or Rabbi Raphael Evers.

Comment: I believe the Dayan of Amsterdam is nowdays Harav Eliezer Wolff.

Comment: If you look for former Dutch authoritative for the Spanish Portuguese tradition, Rabbi Shem tov Gaguine is the one you should look for. His book, Keter Shem Tov, is available on hebrewbooks I believe. You could find more about him if you google him.